# return empty rows if not found on another table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

I am using code below to get data from database.

```
$this->db->select('users.id,users.username,users.user_status,users.monthlybasepoints,Badges_benefits.nick,Badges_benefits.statusmultiplier,users.intellipoints,payment_info.minpayout,users.earning')
        ->where('status',3)
        ->from('users')
        ->join('Badges_benefits','Badges_benefits.id=users.user_status')
        ->join('payment_info','payment_info.u_id=users.id')
         ->limit($limit,$offset)
        ->order_by($orderby,$order);
        $que= $this->db->get();
        return $que->result_array();
```

it is returning me the output below.

```
sr   name   val metal   code    minpayout  earn
1   liz     0   zinc    120     $22        $0   
2   ahs226  70  Silver  105     $50        $2.1
```

---

```
->join('payment_info','payment_info.u_id=users.id')
```

as i have only 2 rows in table payment info, so it is giving me two outputs only. whereas i want that it should list all rows from table users and can output the value of minpayout as null if nothing mathced in table payment info
like this.

```
sr   name   val metal   code    minpayout  earn
1   liz     0   zinc    120     $22        $0   
2   ahs226  70  Silver  105     $50        $2.1
3    sdasd  34  any     343       null       $34
3    sdasd  34  any     343       null       $24
```

Comment: a good reference on table joins. see here https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join instead of inner join:

```
$this->db->select('users.id,users.username,users.user_status,users.monthlybasepoints,Badges_benefits.nick,Badges_benefits.statusmultiplier,users.intellipoints,payment_info.minpayout,users.earning')
        ->where('status',3)
        ->from('users')
        ->join('Badges_benefits','Badges_benefits.id=users.user_status', 'left')
        ->join('payment_info','payment_info.u_id=users.id', 'left')
         ->limit($limit,$offset)
        ->order_by($orderby,$order);
        $que= $this->db->get();
        return $que->result_array();
```

Comment: thanks. you saved my day.But, really that was too silly for me to not to think of that.